# OpenCV - HOG(Histogram of Gradients) compute doesn't work for portion of the image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, histogram

I am using OpenCV *hogdescriptor* to compute the hog descriptor of different blocks of an image.

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('test.jpg',0)
dim = (450,274)
im = cv2.resize(im.astype(float), dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
winSize = (68,112)
blockSize = (34,28)
blockStride = (17,14)
cellSize = (17,14)
nbins = 9
hog =cv2.HOGDescriptor(winSize,blockSize,blockStride,cellSize,nbins)
hist=hog.compute(im[1:69,1:113].astype('uint8'))
```

The problem is that the code doesn't work when I try to calculate hog descriptor for a portion of the image, but when I switch to the whole image it works. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My question: is there something wrong with the choice of parameters? Do, I need to change the value of other parameters like `nlevels`?

My second question is about the choice of other parameters like `derivAperture`,
`winSigma`, `histogramNormType`, `L2HysThreshold`, `gammaCorrection`, and `nlevels`, can I simply use the values in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28390614/opencv-hogdescripter-python)? Is the value of **`winSigma`** in the mentioned post large for a block of (68,112) size? In particular, I am not sure about the role that **`nlevels`** plays, for example what happens if I change it to 1?

I also checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31158790/hog-features-for-blocks-only?rq=1), but it is not useful for me since it is not using *hogdescriptor*.

Edit: Here is the image I'm using:
[image].

I tried 2 other images, and it doesn't work on those images as well. The code works up to the last line, but when it reaches *hog.compute* it stops with this message:
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.

Comment: Uploading the image and what you have obtained will be of help...

Comment: Please see my edit with the error that I get, and image I've been using.

Comment: [THIS PAGE](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html) has some of the variables you are looking for

Comment: I've seen this page, but I'm not sure about the meaning of nLevels they way it has been described and appreciate if someone can explain it to me. I had to eventually implement hog, since this function was of no use to me. But, I'm still curious  about what to do with the error that I get, and why It doesn't work on a block of image.